# Converting a list to a CSV file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to Convert a list returned by an API to a defined table with rows and columns using pandas.
but for some reason, it has been returning an error.  Below is my code and error as well.

```
import requests
import pprint
import json
import pandas as pd


url = "https://yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com/api/yahoo/ga/topgainers"

querystring = {"start":"0"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "9efd0f3e52mshd859f5daf34a429p11cb2ajsn2b0e421d681e"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
data = response.json()

#print(response.text)


def new_stock(data):
    new_market = []

    for item in data ['quotes']:
        new_name = item.get ('longName')
        new_price = item.get ('regularMarketPrice')
        res_price = (f'{new_price} Dollars')
        cap =item.get('marketCap')
        new_market.append((new_name, res_price, cap))

    return new_market

value = new_stock(data)



def new_list(share_value):
    new = []

    for items in share_value:
        JSONContent = value
        if 'error' not in JSONContent:
            new.append([JSONContent['longName'], JSONContent['regularMarketPrice'], JSONContent['marketCap']])

    return new

dataset = pd.read_csv(new_stock(value))
df = dataset.DataFrame
base = dataset.sample(3)
```

I keep getting this error in return :

```
   for item in data ['quotes']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: It seems to me like data is a list rather than dictionary. Does your request result in success (`response.status_code ==200' )?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at `dataset = pd.read_csv(new_stock(value))`. 
At this point, `value` is a list of tuples and not a dictionary as you expect.

I think that you by mistake trying to process it again with `new_stock` function instead of using somehow the other function you defined (`new_list`) and is not used in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `json_normalize` instead?

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
data = response.json()

df = pd.json_normalize(data, ['quotes'])
print(df.head())

  language region quoteType  triggerable currency  ...  earningsTimestamp  earningsTimestampStart  earningsTimestampEnd  epsForward  forwardPE
0       US   ENUS    EQUITY        False      USD  ...                NaN                     NaN                   NaN         NaN        NaN
1       US   ENUS    EQUITY        False      USD  ...       1.584031e+09            1.584031e+09          1.584031e+09       -0.80 -18.237500
2       US   ENUS    EQUITY        False      USD  ...       1.588696e+09            1.588696e+09          1.588696e+09       -7.07 -17.314003
3       US   ENUS    EQUITY        False      USD  ...       1.587672e+09            1.595635e+09          1.596067e+09        0.95  52.452633
4       US   ENUS    EQUITY        False      USD  ...       1.587673e+09            1.595522e+09          1.595867e+09        1.72  26.040697

[5 rows x 71 columns]
```

You can also save it to csv:

```
df.to_csv('yahoo.csv')
```